# How would I take an image in center in mobile reponsive

Tags: html, css

how would I take an image in center in mobile reponsive

This is my index.html code

```
    <div class="iteams">
<div class="width8 os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInRight" data-os-animation-delay="1.5s"><h2>our <br>products</h2> <img src="images/zig.png" alt=""/></div>
    </div>
```

This is my responsive.css code

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.iteams h2{
    text-align: center;
}
.iteams img{
    margin 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Does the image align in a wrong way? Do you have an example? What framework are you using or is this your own code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set container `div` `.width8` to `margin: 0 auto;` instead of img (also, you were missing a closing `}` for the `@media` query)

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .iteams h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .iteams .width8 {
    margin 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="iteams">
  <div class="width8 os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInRight" data-os-animation-delay="1.5s">
    <h2>our <br>products</h2> 
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center an image, it is recommended to give the parent element an width.
So in your case:

`.iteams{width: 100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

One way to center the image is to use position: relative; along with left: 50%; and transform: translate(-50%); instead of margin: 0px auto;

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .iteams h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .iteams .width8 {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="iteams">
  <div class="width8 os-animation" data-os-animation="slideInRight" data-os-animation-delay="1.5s">
    <h2>our <br>products</h2> 
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.iteams {display:flex justiify-content:center}
```